# Converting Resolutions to Aspect Ratios with PHP

Tags: php, string, image, image-processing

I need some help with something that is probably very basic. I'm working on a PHP function that receives these possible input strings (these are examples, it could be any resolution):

```
1600x900
1440x900
1366x768
1360x768
1280x1024
1280x800
1024x1024
1024x768
640x960
320x480
320x480
etc
```

I'd like to process any one of these strings and return the appropriate aspect ratio string, in this format:

```
5:4
4:3
16:9
etc
```

Any thoughts on a simple way to approach this problem?

Edit: Here's a reference chart I've been working with:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Vector_Video_Standards2.svg

Edit: Here's the answer in JavaScript:

```
aspectRatio: function(a, b) {
    var total = a + b;
    for(var i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        var arx = i * 1.0 * a / total;
        var brx = i * 1.0 * b / total;
        if(i == 40 || (
                Math.abs(arx - Math.round(arx)) <= 0.02 &&
                Math.abs(brx - Math.round(brx)) <= 0.02)) {
            // Accept aspect ratios within a given tolerance
            return Math.round(arx)+':'+Math.round(brx);
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following function may work better:

```
function aspectratio($a,$b){
 # sanity check
 if($a<=0 || $b<=0){
    return array(0,0);
 }
 $total=$a+$b;
 for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++){
  $arx=$i*1.0*$a/$total;
  $brx=$i*1.0*$b/$total;
  if($i==40||(
       abs($arx-round($arx))<=0.02 &&
       abs($brx-round($brx))<=0.02)){
   # Accept aspect ratios within a given tolerance
   return array(round($arx),round($brx));
  }
 }
}
```

I place this code in the public domain.

Comment: As I said, the function is not exact.  As written, the function expects integers for all values.  I will retest the method in PHP and update my answer as soon as I have access to a command-line interpreter.

Comment: My mistake, I wrote `$i=0` instead of the correct `$i=1`.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Also, can you explain your thought process of writing the above function and a little more how it works? I'd love to start to think like you when approaching problems like this.

Comment: Well as you stated in one the comments, using the GCD
function to compute aspect ratio may return inappropriate,
even though exact, results.  Thus, in this case, it may
be more appropriate to use approximate aspect ratios that
approach the exact ratio by a certain tolerance.  However,
having to explain "my thought process" on this answer
in more detail is a bit off topic for this site.

Answer (score 3):

I would approach it this way:

```
$numbers = explode($input,'x');
$numerator = $numbers[0];
$denominator = $numbers[1];
$gcd = gcd($numerator, $denominator);
echo ($numerator / $gcd) . ":" . ($denominator / $gcd);
```

You have to define the gcd function if you don't have the GMP — GNU Multiple Precision extension installed.  There are examples in the [comments of the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-gcd.php#86931).

Comment: This is working great, but it's reporting 1366x768 as being 683:384 and not 16:9. Thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Find the GCD of the width and height of the resolution. Divide by this GCD, and you get the two aspect ratio numbers.

Edit: Brian said it better =]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't a simple problem if you are referring to *all* possible screens.  For example, here's a 1024x1024 screen that's 16:9: http://www.hdtvsolutions.com/AKAI-PDP-4225M.htm

For square-pixels (most computer monitors) the GCD approach suggested by others will work.